# Range Hood CFMs: Sufficient Air vs Avoiding Make-Up Air

Tags: range-hood

When searching for information about the necessary CFMs for a range hood, diy.stackexchange.com has two highly upvoted questions:

1. [How many CFM for a range hood do I REALLY need?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11110/how-many-cfm-for-a-range-hood-do-i-really-need#)

This is relatively active question, currently with 8 answers and 29 upvotes. There the consensus is that, in many cases, you need A LOT of CFMs, especially with higher BTU ranges. So, for instance, if you have a 6-burner stove with 16k burners, one answer there suggests that you need 1,000 BTUs.

But... there is a substantial issue that isn't addressed (as much as I'd like) in answers to that question, which is better addressed in this question:

2. [Do I really need a 1200 CFM Hood for a 48" Range?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/219331/do-i-really-need-a-1200-cfm-hood-for-a-48-range)

There's only 1 answer to this question, but the answerer raises the point that home ranges are infrequently used, and that there is a substantial downside to high CFM range hoods: If you don't provide make-up air (which is expensive), they create negative pressure in a well-sealed house.

Where I'm writing, the building officials use the IRC which requires make-up air that comes on automatically with the range hood, if the CFMs are over 400. So there really is a trade-off here.

What I'm interested in knowing is how one should go about balancing these two considerations, which largely involves information that isn't addressed in the above two questions. I think what's helpful to most people is information that will tell them whether they'll regret undersizing their range hood, and why. Perhaps, a high-BTU stove will heat-up the kitchen too much, or excess grease will be problematic for cleaning, odors from the kitchen will make the house smell like food for a bit, or the air in the kitchen will be unhealthy. I really don't know. What are the concerns, and are they *really* a problem that would justify the expense of adding make-up air for your hood?

Comment: It sounds as if you're asking for a canonical question on this topic to direct people to -- unfortunately, it depends on their current situation (island stoves are notoriously annoying, and so are people who are allergic to having a hood that actually comes down enough to get good capture efficiency; furthermore, gas vs electric vs induction complicates the matter)

Comment: it should be adjustable flow so that you can have it on a little when making eggs, a lot when using 4 burners to cook greasy food. it should be running just fast enough to dissapear the smoke/vapor.